# Positive definite matrix implies a generating set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, linear-programming, positive-definite

> If the matrix $$\sum_{i=1}^my^i(y^i)^T$$ is positive definite, then the set $\{y^1,\dots,y^m\}\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is a a generating set for $\mathbb R^n$

Does anyone know how I can prove that?

Comment: well, not if $m < n.$  The matrix of inner products is called the Gramian or Gram matrix  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

Comment: @WillJagy But the condition that the matrix is positive definite implies $m=n$.

Comment: @kimchilover no, it only implies that $m \geq n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ denote the span of $\{y^1,\dots,y^m\}$. Note that the orthogonal complement $U^\perp$ is the set
$$
U^\perp = \{x \in \Bbb R^n : x^Ty^1 = x^Ty^2 = \cdots = x^Ty^m = 0\}.
$$
So, suppose that $M = \sum_{i=1}^my^i(y^i)^T$ is positive definite.  It follows that for any non-zero $x \in \Bbb R^n$, we have
$$
0 < x^TMx = x^T\left(\sum_{i=1}^my^i(y^i)^T\right)x = \sum_{i=1}^m x^Ty^i(y^i)^Tx = 
\sum_{i=1}^m (x^Ty^i)^2.
$$
In other words: for every $x \in \Bbb R^n$, we have $x^Ty^i \neq 0$ for some $i$ from $1$ to $m$. In other words, every non-zero $x \in \Bbb R^n$ is **not** an element of $U^\perp$.  So, we have $U^\perp = \{0\}$, which means that $U = U^{\perp \perp} = \Bbb R^n$.  So, the span of the vectors $y^1,\dots,y^m$ is $\Bbb R^n$, which is to say that these vectors form a generating set for $\Bbb R^n$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix is symmetric and thus has a basis consisting of eigenvectors. It is also positive semi-definite since $v^\top \left(\sum_{i=1}^m y^i (y^i)^\top \right) v = \sum_{i=1}^m (v^\top y^i)^2 \ge 0$ for all $v$.

Thus it is positive definite if and only if its nullspace is empty. One can check that the nullspace of this matrix consists of vectors that are orthogonal to each of the $y^i$. So if the matrix is positive definite, then the $y^i$ must span $\mathbb{R}^n$.